# Android emulator fails to start when used with tcpdump-option

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, tcpdump

When I run an AVD from the Terminal on Ubuntu 14.04, the following command is working without problems:

```
my_name@host:~$ emulator -avd my_avd
```

But when I want to use tcpdump to capture the network-traffic, the emulator fails to start:

```
my_name@host:~$ emulator -avd my_avd -tcpdump ~/test.cap
qemu-system-i386: -tcpdump: invalid option
```

I have no problems running the emulator with tcpdump on Windows, but on Ubuntu and Debian it refuses to work. Might this be a Bug or am I missing something? The same problem occurrs when I want to use the option `-timezone Europe/Berlin`. In contrast, the option `-dns-option 8.8.8.8` is working fine. The problem occurrs for every AVD.

Android SDK:

- SDK Tools 25.1.1
- Platform-Tools 23.1
- Build-Tools 23.0.3
- Android 6.0 SDK Platform Revision 3
- Android 6.0 (Intel x86 Atom Image 32/64 Bit Revision 8 and ARM EABI v7a Image Revision 3)

Virtualization (KVM) is enabled on Intel Core 2 Duo. Oracle JDK 8 is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same behavior occurred on my Mac, the solution seems to be to add `-engine classic` to your command line call. So it reads:

```
my_name@host:~$ emulator -avd my_avd -tcpdump ~/test.cap -engine classic
```

Credits go to @Interix for posting this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934521/android-emulator-fails-to-start-when-used-with-tcpdump-option-on-windows10)

Answer (score -1):

According to your emulator, -tcpdump is an invalid option.  Check emulator -? or man emulator for the syntax.  However, I'd be surprised if this would normally work at all - I haven't seen tcpdump integrated with anything as an argument by itself (though I'm sure it's not impossible).

Normally I'd expect to use tcpdump as a command by itself.  Depending what tools you have installed, I'd run up the emulator, check what ports it's running, and run tcpdump against its port range separately if you're looking for incoming traffic.  If it's outgoing, use tcpdump to trace the traffic to the destination you're going to use.

Comment: I already read the help output (on both systems) so I know that there is an option `-tcpdump <filename>`. The tcpdump option is working on Windows, but on Linux it tells me "invalid option".