# Android emulator fails to start when used with tcpdump-option on Windows10

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-10, tcpdump, android-virtual-device

I can run an avd using cmd on Windows 10 with the command:

```
emulator -avd avdmy
```

but when I want to use tcpdump to capture the network-traffic, the emulator fails to start:

```
emulator -avd avdmy -tcpdump ~/test.cap
qemu-system-i386.exe: -tcpdump: invalid option
```

I have no problems running the emulator itself. Might this be a Bug or am I missing something? The problem occurrs for every AVD I've tried.  I've checked emulator -help and I am sure -tcpdump is an option. My question is do I need tcpdump installed on my Windows before I can get this to work or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

The option "-tcpdump" is not valid in the latest android emulator. It only works with goldfish I guess. You may try option "-engine classic" with "-tcpdump".

Comment: I had similar issues on OS X and this was the solution! Thanks!